# Getting error "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" in xcode when headers are not missing

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

When I try to compile my iPhone app and run it in the simulator I get errors complaining about undefined symbols.
All of these symbols correspond to classes that are in included and not missing in my project.

Example:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKFacebook", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FooAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in FooLandingPageViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in FooAppDelegate.o
```

but SHKFacebook.h is not missing from the project.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have multiple Xcode targets in this project and when I added the files to the project I added them under the wrong target making them not visible to the target I was trying to build.

Answer (score 1):

Is SHKFaceBook.h your file or a file from a library?

If its from a library click on your project target and select the Build Phases tab and then
select the Link Binary With Library section and make sure the library is added.

If SHKFaceBook.h is not from a library then the fact that the .h file is included is irrelevant if the corresponding .m file isn't present. 
If the .m file is already in your XCode project then from the Build Phases tab select Compile Sources and make sure the necessary files are there.

FYI this is a link error, a link error is not the same as a compile error. Source files can compile with just the header, but they cannot be linked and built without the actual code. A header file is not code, it is more like a description of what is in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the library your linking against was only compiled for the arm platform, and not for the i386 - if you have the source try a clean / re-build?